# AWS S3 Upload speed?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I'm uploading my files from a project to S3 bucket in AWS. This is my first time uploading a project with AWS so I'm not sure if it usually take this long but its saying it will take over 1 day.

I also have turned on transfer acceleration and turned off everything running in the background which helped but it still seems like a long wait.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are uploading a large number of files via a web browser. This would involve overhead for each file and is likely single-threaded.

I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to upload the files. It can upload multiple files simultaneously to take advantage of your bandwidth.

Also, it has the `aws s3 sync` command, which can recover from failures by only copying files that have not yet been uploaded. (That is, you can run it multiple times.)